# Visual Studio 2015+ How to configure 32bit vs 64bit run-mode for different ASP.NET solutions within the same machine

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, x86, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

Assume we have two different asp.net solutions solutionA_32bit and solutionB_64bit. As the names suggest, solutionA needs to be run in 32bit mode (aka within a 32bit iis-express) and solutionB needs to be run in 64bit mode (aka within a 64bit iis-express). The only option I've seen so far in order to make these solutions run is to tweak a global option in visual studio which can be found under

```
"Tools -> Options -> Projects And Solutions -> Web Projects -> Use the 64bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects"
```

However the above option -being global- means that:

A. we have to switch it back and forth depending on whether solution A or B is being developed

and B. if A and B solutions need to be run in parallel (e.g. because there is some sort of cross communication going on between their backends) then we are between a rock and a hard place.

Is there any way to achieve the desired effect on a per-solution basis?

Addendum:

Turns out that at the time of this writing there isn't a way to achieve the desired effect. If you feel hurt by this please drop an upvote or two on this feature-suggestion here:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/18645511-move-the-use-the-64-bit-version-of-iis-express-fo

Comment: Was hoping that I was missing something obvious but from the looks of it there's no easy way to achieve the desired effect in an out-of-the-box fashion. I imagine one has to resort to using registry hacks in the post-build events to get things working which is unfathomably ugly of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's not an answer but more a work around : why not use the full fledged IIS for the 64 bits. It should be a tad easier to live with.

PS: I searched 5 sec on https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/ and found that : https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/4899675-move-the-use-the-64-bit-version-of-iis-express-fo

tl,dr;
We forgot to add it to the backlog, again, please insist (I don't think they want to do it).

Sorry ;)

Comment: Well for the time being this is the closest thing to a closure. Thanks for lookign into this.